# Multiple UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, webview

Ok, so I am an extremely novice programmer. I know next to nothing (which is why I am asking you guys.) So, I built a tab bar application in xcode to run on my iPhone. (I used this turorial: http://fuelyourcoding.com/creating-a-tab-bar-application-using-storyboards-in-xcode-4-2/) Everything from that point of view works great, the tabs all go to the correct pages and I know how to add more pages if I want to. The problem that I am coming across is that I want a good amount of the tabs to be web views. The problem that I am facing is that I can get the first view controller to work (thanks to this tutorial: http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/) but I have no idea how to get another one to do the same thing. I have googled and what I get is just a bunch of code that I have no idea where to put. Any help?

Comment: A little hard to tell what it is you're trying to do (or rather what isn't working). Configuring a second (or third, or fourth) UIWebView is no different than configuring the first one...

Comment: Can you post some code from your AppDelegate.m that sets up the TabViewController?